# Transforming Web.Config in a Windows Docker container

Tags: docker, octopus-deploy, docker-for-windows

I have a .NET app that uses Octopus to deploy to the server. In this process, Octopus updates some of the values in the Web.Config (API keys, database connection string etc). I'm moving this app into a container on the same server, and the image has been built before Octopus gets anywhere near it.

How do I update the Web.Config based on the environment in which the `docker run` command is being triggered?

I've found [this](http://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-web-config-transforms-docker-containers/) blog post, which seems to necessitate a config transformation file.

I could also pass everything in as environment variables to the container, but then I'd have to change how the app accesses them, which I don't want to do because there are lots of other apps to be done.

Comment: What is wrong with "environment" variable path? This is common approach to modify running container for different environments

Comment: Just that I don't want to modify the C# in the app that's doing `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Whatever"]`

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying. Update question with details of what you are doing and what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I have the same issue with Docker. My code contains something like `ConfigurationManage.AppSettings["SomeSetting"]`, and I cannot change the source code, so I want to alter Web.config file *after* container is deployed.

Comment: @VladimirPanchenko in the end I used a powershell script that took in environment variables and updated the Web.Config